# Select Top product from multiple tables combine the duplicates products and SUM the quantity

Tags: sql, postgresql

I a have multiple sells lists tables i want to select the top product of each table (the higher quantity value) and "the validated sells only in their master tables" from each sells list table then select the top product of all tables.
This is what i did so far:

```
  SELECT code_p, SUM(total) 
  FROM (   
  SELECT code_p as code_p, SUM(qty_p) as total from table1_sells_list d 
  INNER JOIN table1 p ON d.code_t1 = p.code_t1 
  WHERE valid_t3 = true 
  GROUP BY code_p, qty_p
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT code_p, SUM(qty_p) as total from table2_sells_list a
  INNER JOIN table2 c ON a.code_t2 = c.code_t2 
  WHERE valider_t3 = true 
  GROUP BY code_p, qty_p
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT code_p, SUM(qty_p) as total from table2_sells_list e
  INNER JOIN table3 f ON e.code_t3 = f.code_t3 
  WHERE valider_t3 = true 
  GROUP BY code_p, qty_p
      ) a 
  GROUP BY code_p, total
  ORDER BY code_p, total DESC
```

The result is this:

[image]

As you can see there is two rows with the same product, what i wanna do is to combine the duplicated rows and SUM the sum like this :

[image]

Comment: You don't want to look at sales *between* tables?  Also, sample data would help clarify what you are doing.

Comment: Just remove `total` from last `GROUP BY code_p`.

Comment: @klin Well this worked just fine but i had to change the field name at the top of the query to something else other than `totat` , otherwise it will throw `must appear in the GROUP BY clause` error . 
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the whole query in a

```
SELECT code_p, sum(sum)
FROM ( <your original query> ) x
GROUP BY code_p;
```

Comment: Thank you it woks , _klin_ here notice me for something quit easy and faster i guess in his comment , but your concept are so helpful  thanks